# create array of tags from string that might have commas or spaces

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, tags

I need to create an array of tags to pass to the WordPress `tags_input` inside the `wp_insert_post()` function.
These tags are user-input. I ask the user to separate by comma but I know some users won't do that and will just write words, so if a user inputs "The Rolling Stones" and another one inputs "The,Rolling,Stones" how can I make sure my array will always contain:

```
$wp_tags = array("the","rolling","stones");
```

can I do this?

```
$wp_tags = array( "'" . preg_replace("!\s+!","','",strtolower($_POST['user_tags'])). "'" );
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to convert the input string to lowercase, then `preg_split()` on one or more non-alphanumeric characters.  Or if you want Stack Overflow-like rules, include hyphens in your negated character class.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that to do what I wanted to need a combination of my code attempt and explode(), like so:

```
$wp_tags = explode(",",(preg_replace("!\s+!",",",strtolower($_POST['user_tags']))));

// strtolower makes it all lowercase
// preg_replace replaces all single/multiple white spaces with a comma
// explode uses those commas to split all the words and enter them into the array
```